# Factorisation of functions on the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f\in H^{\infty} \subset H^1 $ where $H^p$ are the Hardy spaces on the unit disc. As usual, we could factorise $f = Su\Theta$ where $S$ is a singular inner function, $u$ is an inner function (possibly infinite Blaschke product), and $\Theta$ Outer. Since $f$ belongs to $H^{\infty}$, can we conclude that the outer part is 1? Or that $f$ has finitely many zeroes?

Comment: Nothing that is possible to conclude from $f$ being in $H^\infty$.

Comment: Infinite blaschke products have infinitely many zeroes and are bounded by $1$: singular functions have no zeroes but are bounded and there are tons of bounded outer functions